# Is it possible to generate a self-signed certificate with Crypto++?

Tags: c++, crypto++

For a POC system, I have to make a simple application which can generate ECDSA key pairs, and then generate self-signed X509 certificate, and be able to generate certificate to prove possession of others device's public key, without any request, because of simplified version of the POC.

To do this, I have a Qt application and I use the Crypto++ library for generating key pairs and sign or validate all I need.

I saw some examples on the Crypto++ documentation to read and validate an X509 certificate, but nothing to fill or generate it.

For the moment, I make some calls to OpenSSL to generate the self-signed certificate, but I would like to remove this and only use Crypto++. Is there any way to do this? When I look to the X509Certificate prototypes, I can only see reading functions…

Comment: Crypto++ still doesn't support generation of X509 certificates. Are there any updates on this?